# mysql select join second row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

task

```
task_id |  content | date
-------------------------------
1       | task 1   | 2019-11-26
2       | task 2   | 2019-11-27
```

task_child

```
id | task_id | type | date_task
--------------------------------
1  | 1       | A    | 2019-11-26
2  | 1       | B    | 2019-11-27
3  | 1       | A    | 2019-11-28
4  | 1       | B    | 2019-11-28
5  | 2       | A    | 2019-11-26
6  | 2       | B    | 2019-11-26
7  | 2       | C    | 2019-11-28
```

Hi, I have two table as above, how do I join that table in order to get only 2nd row from each task_child?

The result should be like below:

```
task_id | content | type | date_task
------------------------------------
1       | task 1  | B    | 2019-11-27
2       | task 2  | B    | 2019-11-26
```

Comment: Try this, and let me know if this works.

select task.task_id, task.content, task_child.type, task_child.task_date from task, task_child where task.task_id=task_child.task_id and task_child.id=2

Comment: @twister, if you dont want to use `id = 2` you can try using `row_number` and then use that in your `where` condition

Comment: how? any example?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` in a subquery to rank records in the child table within group having the same `task_id`, and use it as a join filter:

```
select t.task_id, t.content, c.type, c.date_task
from task t
inner join (
    select c.*, row_number() over(partition by task_id order by date_task) rn
    from task_child
) c on c.task_id = t.task_id and c.rn = 2
```

In earlier versions, this is a bit more complicated. One solution would be to add a join condition with a subquery that ensures that there is just one record in the child table with the same `task_id` and an earlier `date_task` than the record currently being joined:

```
select t.task_id, t.content, c.type, c.date_task
from task t
inner join task_child c 
    on c.task_id = t.task_id 
    and (
        SELECT count(*) 
        from task_child c1 
        where c1.task_id = c.task_id and c1.date_task < c.date_task
    ) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
   SELECT 
       Task.task_id, 
       Task.content, 
       Task_Child.type,
       Task.task_date
    FROM 
       Task
    INNER JOIN 
       Task_Child 
    ON 
       Task.task_id=Task_Child.task_id;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second status, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select tc.type
        from task_child tc
        where tc.task_id = t.task_id
        order by tc.id
        limit 1, 1
       ) as type
from task t;
```

Given that you want one column, this is probably the most efficient method, regardless of MySQL version.  For best performance, you want an index on `task_child(task_id, id, type)`.